# What should I do if no-one answers my question, even after placing a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620723/is-there-a-non-racy-way-for-a-device-driver-to-add-sysfs-binary-attributes-prior) about a tricky problem I ran in to.  After a few days if it getting 0 answers and 0 comments, I posted a bounty to try to draw attention to the question.  The bounty just expired (although I still have just under 24 hours to reward it, so I'm not sure exactly what "expired" means here), and the question has still gotten 0 answers and 0 comments.

What am I supposed to do at this point?  Give up?  Hope and pray that someone happens to answer my question?  Wait for it to fully expire, then post a larger bounty?

Comment: do more research. improve it. apply another bounty.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Ironically, the standing advice has already been taken and in actuality, I wonder if the question the OP is posting can be answered by the people that normally mill around these parts anyhow...

Comment: @Makoto That's just a strong indication that the question needs improvement (e.g. a [MCVE] or such]).

Comment: @KevinB I've done quite a bit of research, although I'm not sure the best way to show it.  Should I turn my [question](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/7/15/531) [into](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/) [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sysfs.h?v=3.4#L56) [soup](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sysfs.h?v=3.11#L59) detailing my research?  That seems unhelpful.

Comment: well, no it likely wouldn't be helpful. the reality though is if no one is interested in answering it in it's current form... all you can do is change it in such a way that it does interest someone to answer it. past that... there's not much you can do other than sharing it elsewhere.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I will note that this does get us off-topic, but my remark is more towards...I don't believe that very many Linux kernel devs lurk these parts in numbers enough to see a question like this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure how a MCVE would help here.  The question is more theoretical ("Is this possible? If so, how?") than code-specific ("Why does this way of doing it not work").

Comment: @g.rocket _"The question is more theoretical"_ That might be the culprit. SO wants answers for specific things.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "theoretical" was perhaps not the best word; I'm definitely asking for a specific thing: what I was trying to say is that I'm not asking what the problem is with a specific bit of code (I _know_ what the problem is), but rather _if something can be done_.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't see much of a problem with the question.  I'm genuinely thinking about the domain knowledge involved here that would be capable of answering this sort of question.  Do you know of any kernel dev mailing lists that are active?

Comment: I'm crap with coding device drivers for linux.  But I'm much better with clickbait.

Comment: The question is not in my field of expertise but if no one else bytes, I'm willing to put up a higher bounty. Just because that title is nice :)

Comment: @RadLexus Should I have kept the clickbait?

Comment: (umm....) Well it wasn't *that* bad was it? Even then, it only got 55 views - probably including a dozen due to this post. I checked your tags, but I can see nothing wrong with them - although they all seem low bandwidth tags.

Comment: @RadLexus I'll give it a chance.

Comment: @Makoto I've never posted to a mailing list before, and don't really understand how they're supposed to work.  Are there any kernel dev mailing lists that would give me a more useful answer than "Upgrade to Linux 3.11+"?

Comment: I wonder sometimes about getting bites on questions and I find myself wondering why I don't answer on some of the ones I click on. I always thought a quick difficulty/challenge rating (i.e. 1-5 stars) would be a useful addition on SO. That way if you have 40 views and no response at all, but a 4 or 5 challenge rating, you at least can assume your question is sound, it's just that no one has has the time/knowledge to provide a full answer.

Comment: Your question is super-niche and difficult to answer through normal research, so odds are you simply haven't had anybody see the question who knows how to answer it. Finding an appropriate mailing list would be your best bet (if you get an answer from someone who doesn't post on SO, self-answer your question here!). The "clickbait" title is rather silly, but not so bad that I'd expect it to put people off (though remember you need specific knowledge, not lots of viewers, so your use case is quite different from the average spam-news-slinger).

Comment: @Dave The original title was "*Is there a non-racy way for a device driver to add sysfs binary attributes prior to Linux 3.11?*", but some people here suggested I change it to get more views...  I honestly preferred the original title, as it was chock-full of keywords and conveyed pretty much all of the information in the question, but I'll defer to more experienced users (especially if someone offers to place a bounty for me).

Comment: @g.: I cannot put a bounty up until this one has fully expired. I'll keep one eye on it for the mo' (maybe someone else beats me to it). In the mean time, I've sent a link to a sysadmin I know at a supercomputer data center. They have a home grown 7856 core Debian cluster – I guess he ought to know his way around an fs.

Comment: *"What am I supposed to do at this point?"* - Repost the question every ten minutes until somebody pays attention.